# Router link should be active based on child routes

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a setup in which I want the router link to be active for '/heros' also for '/:id/heros'. Is there any way to do this for client and server side rendering?

Comment: your angular router should not care about server side rendering or not the rout paths however - that is not a good design - you should be doing heros/:id - otherwise your catch all route would be anything matching :id which would be almost every single route.  angular cannot differentiate that.

Comment: There is no matching id. I am asking for a big project cannot change the routing structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your routes don't reflect any parent-child-relation. Change them to `/heros` and `/heros/:id`. Then `routerLinkActive` will be active for a link to `/heros` when you're at `/heros/123` by default (when `routerLinkActiveOptions.exact` is not true).

If you can't change your route structure, swap `routerLinkActive` for something custom. For example, keep a boolean BehaviorSubject in a service for flagging when the link should have the active class, and set it to true when entered either of those routes and false when left the route:

```
// heroes.service.ts

heroesActive$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

```
// heroes.component.ts and hero.component.ts

constructor(private heroes:HeroesService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.heroes.heroesActive$.next(true);
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
   this.heroes.heroesActive$.next(false);
}
```

```
// menu.component.ts
constructor(public heroes: HeroesService) { }
```

```
// menu.component.html

<a [class.active]="heroes.heroesActive$ | async" routerLink="/heroes">/heroes</a>
```

Comment: I cannot change the routing structure. That is the task.

Comment: Ok, added another solution for that case.

Comment: then you're router link active will never work - you need to contact whomever wrote the routing and tell them this is against angular best practice.  anyone doing a catch all route that is not lost is asking for very serious problems.

Comment: I agree it's not best practice, but sometimes these things happen early in development and they're impossible to fix later. Maybe there's a CMS for example, which already has hundreds of pages with links pointing to those URLs. Fixing all those links might be difficult in some cases. Also your site would start from zero considering SEO because all the history is lost. Analytics messed up etc.